# icu4c - Updating/installing php after installing Yosemite using Homebrew

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded to Yosemite. I was using Apache 2.2, but the upgrade included 2.4. After some configuration nightmares, I ended up reinstalling 2.4 using Homebrew. I have it mostly configured. However, when I use the old httpd.conf settings for php, I get the following error:

> Symbol not found: _unixd_config\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n  Expected in: /usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.10/bin/httpd\n in /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

When running `brew upgrade php55` I get the following error when updating icu4c:

```
==> Upgrading icu4c
==> Downloading http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/54.1/icu4c-54_1-src.tgz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 8c752490bbf31cea26e20246430cee67d48abe34
Actual: d625398a0d5cb34a0b5b2c4ab577e3b1957fb460
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

Removing the file does not help. I've ran `brew doctor`, which gives me this concerning php:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /usr/local/opt/php55/bin/php-config
```

Not sure how to proceed. I've tried to install php56, but it needs the same dependency. Seems to be a icu4c issue, but this is kind of unchartered territory for me. Thanks

Comment: If you haven't, install xcode 6.1. It's not in app store (yet), but you can download it from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/ -> "Additional Tools" (should be on top of the page)

Comment: @PerS Still get the same SHA1 mismatch error, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you have set for php in your httpd.config?

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with the version of Xcode or GCC, LLVM or Clang you have installed. If you look at the file in question you can see what is happening.

```
[uxp@localhost]% brew install icu4c
==> Downloading http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/54.1/icu4c-54_1-src.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 8c752490bbf31cea26e20246430cee67d48abe34
Actual: a2fd3379ea944f6b2f97fb0f79b7b85cb3e14d0b
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

[uxp@localhost]% file /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz: HTML document text

[uxp@localhost]% cat /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
<html><head>
<title>Testing</title>
<!-- <script src="/js/jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//sourceforge.net/js/mirrors.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sf.js"></script>
<script>
var DR_loc = DR_parse_hash_url();
if (DR_loc) {
    DR_sf_main(DR_loc);
} else {
    window.location.href = 'http://sourceforge.net/home.html';
}
</script>
</head><body>
<noscript>
We're sorry -- the Sourceforge site is currently in Disaster Recovery mode, and currently requires
the use of javascript to function.  Please check back later.
</noscript>
</body></html>
```

So, something is wrong with the server, not your machine. The simplest approach is to contact them and let them deal with it (it's something on SourceForge's end), but that doesn't help you install whatever you wanted that depends on ICU. Looking around the internet, there are some copies on mirror sites of the tar archive we're looking for, so simply downloading it manually and moving into your Homebrew cache directory will suffice.

```
[uxp@localhost]% curl http://dbg.download.sourcemage.org/mirror/icu4c-54_1-src.tgz -o /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 24.3M  100 24.3M    0     0  3669k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 5745k

[uxp@localhost]% brew install icu4c
==> Downloading http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/54.1/icu4c-54_1-src.tgz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/54.1 --disable-samples --disable-tests --enable-static --with-library-bits=64
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
...
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/54.1: 242 files, 65M, built in 74 seconds
```

To be honest, I have no idea if this will solve your problem with Apache and PHP. If you still are having issues with the builtin httpd and php, I would wipe out any versions your have installed through Homebrew including their configuration files in `/usr/local/etc`, upgrade icu4c, and then systematically begin the installation process of Apache, PHP 5.x, and then any php5x-* modules you need in addition again.

I came across the same Homebrew failure trying to reinstall CouchDB, which is entirely different than what your original issue was.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for troubleshooting that for me! I dug around a lot and ended up using a co-worker's copy and it worked... It was something on icu4c's end. After getting that worked out I was able to update PHP fine. I also did end up wiping my Apache install from Homebrew and reconfigured the original installation. It took a while but got it working correctly. Thanks again.